# PyQt5 function setVisible not working in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt5

I'm trying to change visibility of button after particular time in PyQt5 and Python but it's not working. it showing this error in console

self.done_btn.setVisible(True)
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'done_btn'

**Before timer**
Button should be hidden

```
done_btn = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'done.png')), "Done", self)
    done_btn.setVisible(False)
    done_btn.triggered.connect(self.start_earning)
    guide.addAction(done_btn)
```

**After Timer**
After timer completed button should be visible

```
def timeout(self):
    self.guidestate.setText('hello world')
    self.done_btn.setVisible(True)
```

**Timer**

```
t = Timer(5, self.timeout)
        t.start()
```

Comment: you define : done_btn = QAction(....) ,and trying to use  self.done_btn (in def timeout) , define your btn like : self.done_btn = QAction(...)

Comment: you're welcome :)